# What is invalid in my C language code for AVRs in codevision?

Tags: c, avr

In the below you can see whole of my program that is written in Codevision (C language.). When I want to compile it, I receive some errors for *Switch* blocks! I am pretty sure my block's form are correct! would you please take a look?

```
*******************************************************
This program was created by the
CodeWizardAVR V3.12 Advanced
Automatic Program Generator
© Copyright 1998-2014 Pavel Haiduc, HP InfoTech s.r.l.
http://www.hpinfotech.com

Project : 
Version : 
Date    : 12/17/2014
Author  : 
Company : 
Comments: 


Chip type               : ATmega32
Program type            : Application
AVR Core Clock frequency: 8.000000 MHz
Memory model            : Small
External RAM size       : 0
Data Stack size         : 512
*******************************************************/

#include <mega32.h>

// Standard Input/Output functions
#include <stdio.h>

#include <delay.h>

#include <stdint.h>


// Declare your global variables here
#define SCANS;


void sendNum(int);
void resetWrongTryCounter();
void sendSpecialChars(char);

// External Interrupt 0 service routine
interrupt [EXT_INT0] void ext_int0_isr(void)
{
// Place your code here

}



void main(void)
{
// Declare your local variables here
int num=9999;

OSCCAL=0xA0;


// Input/Output Ports initialization
// Port A initialization
// Function: Bit7=Out Bit6=Out Bit5=Out Bit4=Out Bit3=In Bit2=In Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRA=(1<<DDA7) | (1<<DDA6) | (1<<DDA5) | (1<<DDA4) | (0<<DDA3) | (0<<DDA2) | (0<<DDA1) | (0<<DDA0);
// State: Bit7=1 Bit6=1 Bit5=1 Bit4=1 Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTA=(1<<PORTA7) | (1<<PORTA6) | (1<<PORTA5) | (1<<PORTA4) | (0<<PORTA3) | (0<<PORTA2) | (0<<PORTA1) | (0<<PORTA0);

// Port B initialization
// Function: Bit7=In Bit6=In Bit5=In Bit4=In Bit3=In Bit2=In Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRB=(0<<DDB7) | (0<<DDB6) | (0<<DDB5) | (0<<DDB4) | (0<<DDB3) | (0<<DDB2) | (0<<DDB1) | (0<<DDB0);
// State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=T Bit4=T Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTB=(0<<PORTB7) | (0<<PORTB6) | (0<<PORTB5) | (0<<PORTB4) | (0<<PORTB3) | (0<<PORTB2) | (0<<PORTB1) | (0<<PORTB0);

// Port C initialization
// Function: Bit7=In Bit6=In Bit5=In Bit4=In Bit3=In Bit2=In Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRC=(0<<DDC7) | (0<<DDC6) | (0<<DDC5) | (0<<DDC4) | (0<<DDC3) | (0<<DDC2) | (0<<DDC1) | (0<<DDC0);
// State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=T Bit4=T Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTC=(0<<PORTC7) | (0<<PORTC6) | (0<<PORTC5) | (0<<PORTC4) | (0<<PORTC3) | (0<<PORTC2) | (0<<PORTC1) | (0<<PORTC0);

// Port D initialization
// Function: Bit7=In Bit6=In Bit5=In Bit4=In Bit3=In Bit2=In Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRD=(0<<DDD7) | (0<<DDD6) | (0<<DDD5) | (0<<DDD4) | (0<<DDD3) | (0<<DDD2) | (0<<DDD1) | (0<<DDD0);
// State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=T Bit4=T Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTD=(0<<PORTD7) | (0<<PORTD6) | (0<<PORTD5) | (0<<PORTD4) | (0<<PORTD3) | (0<<PORTD2) | (0<<PORTD1) | (0<<PORTD0);

// Timer/Counter 0 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer 0 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC0 output: Disconnected
TCCR0=(0<<WGM00) | (0<<COM01) | (0<<COM00) | (0<<WGM01) | (0<<CS02) | (0<<CS01) | (0<<CS00);
TCNT0=0x00;
OCR0=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer1 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFFFF
// OC1A output: Disconnected
// OC1B output: Disconnected
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: Off
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off
TCCR1A=(0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (0<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (0<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
TCCR1B=(0<<ICNC1) | (0<<ICES1) | (0<<WGM13) | (0<<WGM12) | (0<<CS12) | (0<<CS11) | (0<<CS10);
TCNT1H=0x00;
TCNT1L=0x00;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;
OCR1AH=0x00;
OCR1AL=0x00;
OCR1BH=0x00;
OCR1BL=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 2 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer2 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC2 output: Disconnected
ASSR=0<<AS2;
TCCR2=(0<<PWM2) | (0<<COM21) | (0<<COM20) | (0<<CTC2) | (0<<CS22) | (0<<CS21) | (0<<CS20);
TCNT2=0x00;
OCR2=0x00;

// Timer(s)/Counter(s) Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK=(0<<OCIE2) | (0<<TOIE2) | (0<<TICIE1) | (0<<OCIE1A) | (0<<OCIE1B) | (0<<TOIE1) | (0<<OCIE0) | (0<<TOIE0);

// External Interrupt(s) initialization
// INT0: On
// INT0 Mode: Low level
// INT1: Off
// INT2: Off
GICR|=(0<<INT1) | (1<<INT0) | (0<<INT2);
MCUCR=(0<<ISC11) | (0<<ISC10) | (0<<ISC01) | (0<<ISC00);
MCUCSR=(0<<ISC2);
GIFR=(0<<INTF1) | (1<<INTF0) | (0<<INTF2);

// USART initialization
// Communication Parameters: 8 Data, 1 Stop, No Parity
// USART Receiver: Off
// USART Transmitter: On
// USART Mode: Asynchronous
// USART Baud Rate: 9600
UCSRA=(0<<RXC) | (0<<TXC) | (0<<UDRE) | (0<<FE) | (0<<DOR) | (0<<UPE) | (0<<U2X) | (0<<MPCM);
UCSRB=(0<<RXCIE) | (0<<TXCIE) | (0<<UDRIE) | (0<<RXEN) | (1<<TXEN) | (0<<UCSZ2) | (0<<RXB8) | (0<<TXB8);
UCSRC=(1<<URSEL) | (0<<UMSEL) | (0<<UPM1) | (0<<UPM0) | (0<<USBS) | (1<<UCSZ1) | (1<<UCSZ0) | (0<<UCPOL);
UBRRH=0x00;
UBRRL=0x33;

// Analog Comparator initialization
// Analog Comparator: Off
// The Analog Comparator's positive input is
// connected to the AIN0 pin
// The Analog Comparator's negative input is
// connected to the AIN1 pin
ACSR=(1<<ACD) | (0<<ACBG) | (0<<ACO) | (0<<ACI) | (0<<ACIE) | (0<<ACIC) | (0<<ACIS1) | (0<<ACIS0);
SFIOR=(0<<ACME);

// ADC initialization
// ADC disabled
ADCSRA=(0<<ADEN) | (0<<ADSC) | (0<<ADATE) | (0<<ADIF) | (0<<ADIE) | (0<<ADPS2) | (0<<ADPS1) | (0<<ADPS0);

// SPI initialization
// SPI disabled
SPCR=(0<<SPIE) | (0<<SPE) | (0<<DORD) | (0<<MSTR) | (0<<CPOL) | (0<<CPHA) | (0<<SPR1) | (0<<SPR0);

// TWI initialization
// TWI disabled
TWCR=(0<<TWEA) | (0<<TWSTA) | (0<<TWSTO) | (0<<TWEN) | (0<<TWIE);

// Global enable interrupts
#asm("sei")
while (num>-1)
      {
        resetWrongTryCounter();
        delay_ms(100);
        sendNum(num/1000);
        delay_ms(25);
        sendNum((num%1000)/100); 
        delay_ms(25);
        sendNum((num%100)/10);
        delay_ms(25);
        sendNum(num%10);
        delay_ms(500);
        --num;     
      }      
}

void sendNum(int num)
{
    uint8_t count;
    switch(num){
        case 0  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.0 != 0);
                PORTA.5 = 0;
                while (PINA.0 != 1);
                PORTA.5 = 1;
            }
            break; 
            
        case 1  :
            for(count=0;count<SCANS;count++){
                while (PINA.1 != 0);
                PORTA.4 = 0;
                while (PINA.1 != 1);
                PORTA.4 = 1;
            }
            break; 
            
        case 2  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.2 != 0);
                PORTA.4 = 0;
                while (PINA.2 != 1);
                PORTA.4 = 1;
            }
            break; 
            
        case 3  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.3 != 0);
                PORTA.4 = 0;
                while (PINA.3 != 1);
                PORTA.4 = 1;
            }
            break;
             
        case 4  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.1 != 0);
                PORTA.5 = 0;
                while (PINA.1 != 1);
                PORTA.5 = 1;
            }
            break;
             
        case 5  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.2 != 0);
                PORTA.5 = 0;
                while (PINA.2 != 1);
                PORTA.5 = 1;
            }
            break; 
            
        case 6  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.3 != 0);
                PORTA.5 = 0;
                while (PINA.3 != 1);
                PORTA.5 = 1;
            }
            break;
             
        case 7  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.1 != 0);
                PORTA.6 = 0;
                while (PINA.1 != 1);
                PORTA.6 = 1;
            }
            break;     
            
        case 8  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.2 != 0);
                PORTA.6 = 0;
                while (PINA.2 != 1);
                PORTA.6 = 1;
            }
            break;
            

        case 9  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
                while (PINA.3 != 0);
                PORTA.6 = 0;
                while (PINA.3 != 1);
                PORTA.6 = 1;
            }
            break;  
              

    }
}


void sendSpecialChars(char ch)
{
    uint8_t count;
    switch(ch){
        case '*'  :
          for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
            while (PINA.0 != 0);
            PORTA.4 = 0;
            while (PINA.0 != 1);
            PORTA.4 = 1;
            }
           break;
           
         case '#'  :
            for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
              while (PINA.0 != 0);
              PORTA.6 = 0;
              while (PINA.0 != 1);
              PORTA.6 = 1;
            }
            
            break; 
    }
}


void resetWrongTryCounter()
{
    PORTA.7=0;
    delay_ms(50);
    PORTA.7=1;
    delay_ms(50);
    sendNum(4);
    sendNum(3);
    sendNum(2);
    sendNum(1);
    sendSpecialChars('#');   
}
```

This is errors that I receive on compile :
[image]

**Update:**

Base on Dear Wintermute's answer, I change the code.
That was right. I change that line to

## define SCANS 8;

Most of errors disappear, But these below errors remain :
[image]

Comment: Tha compiler doesn't know what `PINA` is. I think you are missing the `#define` for `PINA`.

Comment: The suspicious-looking `PINA.2` stuff is a language extension in Codevision, I believe. It should come from `<mega32.h>`.

Comment: Remove the `;` from the define!!! It should be `#define SCANS 8`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
#define SCANS;
```

I am not surprised that

```
for (count=0; count<SCANS; count++){
```

breaks. It expands to

```
for (count=0; count<;; count++){
```

which is an invalid expression. You probably want to `#define SCANS 100` or some other number.

Addendum: Do not use a semicolon in the macro. It will make `SCANS` expand to `8;`, and you'll be left with

```
    for (count=0; count<8;; count++){
```

which is also invalid.

Comment: Thank you dear Wintermute. You was right. But may I ask you take a look to the **Update** section too? Regards :)

Comment: Klas Lindbäck'c comment helped me to solve the second problem (Update) May I ask you to add it to your answer? I want to check it.

Comment: I just did, with a short explanation of what happens if you leave the semicolon.